# Carrying on Chol HaMoed

Tags: halacha, chol-hamoed, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

I once heard there is a Chazzon Ish that speaks about a possible prohibition about carrying (without any need for it) on Chol HaMoed? Is there any such Chazzon Ish or perhaps other poskim that speak about this (either way?)

Comment: Why would there not be a prohibition? All melachot are prohibited on Chol Hamoed unless there is a reason to permit it

Comment: @doubleaa where does it say that (all malachos)

Comment: Shulchan Aruch OC  530

Comment: @DoubleAA ?? Maybe this is from the miktzas malachos that are muter?

Comment: That's what I said. They are all asur unless there is a reason they aren't. What reason might apply here where there is no purpose?

Comment: @DoubleAA See my answer!

Answer (score 4):

See [Shevat HaLevi Chelek 6 Siman 68](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1416&st=&pgnum=74) at the end where he addresses this question. He brings those that are machmir however he says the pashtus from the gemorah (shulchan aruch and poskim) that carrying on chol hamoed is muter even without any essential need to carry.

Comment: @mevaqesh please rephrase your question I don't understand

Comment: If in general melacha is forbidden unless there is some reason to permit it, why would this be different? What is the reason (for those poskim) who are lenient?